# SASS: Existem algum recurso para evitar repetições e linhas de códigos as variações de cores?

Tags: css, front-end, sass, scss

## Situação problema

Estou criando uma paleta de cores que variam muito as suas referências, sendo de 10% da cor base para baixo. Por exemplo:

```
$primary: #0069FF;
```

Uma subtração de 10% desse valor é:

```
$primary-900: #1977FF;
```

Isso, eu vou jogando até `primary-100`, onde o seu valor é de: `#E5F0FF`.

#### Backgrounds variantes

Esses backgrounds também variam, e preciso criar um nome de classe para cada variação de background... por exemplo:

```
.bg-danger-100 {
    background-color: $danger-100;
    color: $danger;
}
.bg-danger-200 {
    background-color: $danger-200;
    color: $danger;
}
(...)

.bg-warning-100 {
    background-color: $danger-100;
    color: $danger;
}
.bg-warning-200 {
    background-color: $danger-200;
    color: $danger;
}
(...)
```

#### Textos variantes

```
.text-danger-100 {
    color: $danger-100;
}
.text-danger-200 {
    color: $danger-200;
}
(...)
```

Isso fica muito trabalhoso a medida que as variações de cores da paleta vão surgindo. E gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que nomeie essas classes, bem como adiciona os valores pertinentes as suas variações?

Existem algum recurso para evitar repetições e linhas de códigos as variações de cores?

Comment: Talvez te de uma luz, tente fazer um @each com darken, para ter um resultado tipo `darken($danger, 10%)`

Comment: Bem... o each com o dark eu cheguei a pensar, mas não sabia o procedimento. Eu cheguei a criar um script que define exatamente essas regras, e ele gera as classes para mim. Eu vou comentar essa publicação com a solução. `&#{$prefix}#{$name} { #{$attribute}: $hex; }`

Answer (score 1):

O Sass trabalha perfeitamente ao nosso favor para automatizar tarefas repetitivas. E para solucionar o problema de criação de classes, é preciso estabelecer alguns conhecimentos básicos.

Primeiro, crie um mixin, no meu caso, chamei de color-modifier. Nele eu recebo alguns parâmetros...

```
@mixin color-modifier($attribute: 'color', $prefix: '-', $effect: 'none', $percent: 0%, $sufix: '') {
}
```

O Legal, é que em atributo, pode-se definir uma propriedade, como `background-color`, `color`, ou dentre outras propriedades pertinentes ou equivalente ao seguinte algoritmo:

```
@mixin color-modifier($attribute: 'color', $prefix: '-', $effect: 'none', $percent: 0%, $sufix: '') {
    @each $name, $hex in $colors {
        @if $effect == none {
            &#{$prefix}#{$name} { #{$attribute}: $hex; }
        } @else if $effect == darken {
            &#{$prefix}#{$name}#{$prefix}#{$sufix} { #{$attribute}: darken($hex, $percent); }
        } @else if $effect == lighten {
            &#{$prefix}#{$name}#{$prefix}#{$sufix} { #{$attribute}: lighten($hex, $percent); }
        }
    }
}
```

Neste algoritmo, a classe é montada de acordo ao parâmetro de 'effect', onde a função darken ou lighten vai escurecer ou clarear uma cor.

Agora, quando eu quero que uma classe herde os valores relativos ao meu mapeamento de cores, basta simplesmente usar a declarativa:

```
.text {
   @include color-modifier(
        $attribute: 'color',
        $prefix: '-',
        $effect: none,
        $percent: 0%,
        $sufix: ''
    );
}
```

Logo, nesse algoritmo tem-se uma saída:

```
.text-primary {
  color: #0069FF;
}
.text-danger {
  color: #D36161;
}
.text-warning {
  color: #FFC107;
}
.text-info {
  color: #17A2B8;
}
.text-indigo {
  color: #7700FF;
}
.text-dark {
  color: #000;
}
```

E pode-se ir muito mais além com o mesmo algoritmo... Por exemplo: Se adicionarmos o efeito, e um sufixo, com a seguinte declarativa como exemplo:

```
@include color-modifier(
        $attribute: 'color',
        $prefix: '-',
        $effect: darken,
        $percent: 10%,
        $sufix: '100'
    );
```

Teremos a seguinte saída:

```
.text-primary-100 {
  color: #0054cc;
}
.text-danger-100 {
  color: #c83939;
}
.text-warning-100 {
  color: #d39e00;
}
.text-info-100 {
  color: #117a8b;
}
.text-indigo-100 {
  color: #5f00cc;
}
.text-dark-100 {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Cara ficou bem massa